# Quel est le sens du mot « délatté » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, paroles-de-chanson

Dans les paroles de la chanson « New-York avec toi », on trouve les lignes suivantes:

> Bercés par le ronron de l'air conditionné
>   Dormir dans un hôtel **délatté**
>   Trainer du côté gay et voir leurs corps se serrer...

Je ne comprends pas le mot *délatté*; je l'ai cherché dans toutes mes références, mais en vain. Que signifie ce mot?

Comment: *Délatter* n'est pas dans le Petit Robert, mais la formation *dé- + latter* est courante. Le mot est dans le [TLF](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=451264320;). Cela dit je comprends que le sens dans le contexte ne soit pas évident.

Comment: Autre lien TLF: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/délatter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The verb "délatter" means "enlever les lattes" (= removing the slats). Clearly an "hotel délatté" is at the lower end of the market.

The expression comes from the slatted base bed. If you remove the slats, it is no more comfortable!

---

La verbe « délatter » veut dire « enlever les lattes ». Clairement un « hôtel délatté » serait à l'extrémité inférieure du marché.

L'expression vient du lit « sommier à lattes ». Si on retire les lattes, il ne serait plus confortable !

Comment: Merci pour la réponse ! Aucun rapport, mais pourquoi as-tu répondu en anglais?

Comment: Je ne sais pas trop quelle est la politique de stackexchange pour les Q&A bilingues, dans le doute je réponds en anglais ;)

Comment: On en discute sur le site meta: http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/2/quelle-est-la-langue-principale-du-site-what-is-the-primary-language-of-the-site et http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/14/answering-in-the-other-language

Comment: Presque, mais non (faux-ami). Voir ma réponse ci-dessous :-)

Comment: Signalons aussi que, dire de l'hôtel qu'il est délatté (et non ses lits), c'est une métonymie.

Comment: @F'x: ça *serait* une métonymie... sauf que délatter n'a jamais été défini comme concernant les lits (un mauvais usage du chanteur n'est certainement pas à exclure).

Comment: ou bien cela n'a rien à voir avec la tenue de l'hôtel comme dans "c'était trop cool le concert ce soir, je suis complètement délatté!"

Answer (score 7):

Il utilise plus probablement « délatté » en allusion à l'état des dormeurs ou de l'ambiance, comme dans « être défoncé, ou délatté », grisé, ivre, en trance.

Voir les paroles d'une autre chanson de H.F. Thiéfaine, « Solexine et Ganja » :

> Le blues m'a délatté mais c'est sans importance
>
> Quand la bière est tirée il faut finir son pack.

Ou encore la chanson « Zazou » de Richard Gotainer :

> C'est l'employé du gag délatté par le swing.

Comment: +1 Le fait que *délatté* s'applique ici au narrateur et non à l'hôtel m'avait toujours paru comme une évidence. Je suis surpris d'autant de réponses cherchant le sens originel de *délatter* pour tenter de le rattacher à l'hôtel. Pour s'en convaincre, une construction analogue serait *conduire une voiture en état d'ivresse*, où personne ne penserait que c'est la voiture qui est ivre...

Answer (score 6):

En effet, « délatter » signifie « enlever les lattes », mais à le terme s'applique aux lattes **de toit** (*roof tiles*, *slates*), non pas de lit (*slats*) [[réf](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.com/d%C3%A9latter/fr-fr/)].

Cela dit, impossible de savoir exactement ce que JL Aubert avait en tête quand il utilisait l'expression. Il est tout à fait possible qu'il ait eu l'intention d'évoquer l'état des lits (mais dans ce cas-là, pourquoi ne pas dire plutôt « dormir dans un lit délatté », plutôt qu'un « *hôtel* délatté »).

Dans les deux cas, elle est assez imagée (peut-être typique de l'argot de l'époque?) pour évoquer un hôtel en mauvais état...

Comment: Peut pas éditer pour un caractère, mais c'est pas slates (ardoises), mais slats...

Comment: @Benjol: thanks... had my two translations tangled up. Fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

Au début, j'ai pensé à « délabré » (et je ne suis pas [le seul](http://www.google.fr/search?q=%22dans+un+hotel+d%C3%A9labr%C3%A9%22+%22New-York+avec+toi%22)).

> En mauvais état, qui tombe en ruine. Synonyme vétuste.

Mais en fait, dans la chanson, c'est bien « délatter » :

> Retirer les lattes de quelque chose. Ex. Retirer les lattes du lit.

Il s'agirait donc d'un hôtel dont les lits n'ont plus de lattes... Je trouve que c'est une bien piètre expression. (Peut-être à la mode dans les années 70 ? En tout cas, les quelques références trouvées par Google pour « hôtel délatté » correspondent toutes à cette chanson...)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMiHkVeH1Io : at 30s, the word used is clearly "délatté"

Comment: Tu veux dire que le mot employé dans la chanson est "délabré" ? C'est faux.

Comment: @Brennan Ouais, en effet! C'est moyen comme expression.

Comment: @Stéphane Tu remarqueras que l'auteur de la page que tu as citée a changé toutes les paroles de la chanson pour en faire une création nouvelle, et non seulement délatté -> délabré.

Comment: @Brennan: J'avais pas vu :-) J'ai changé le lien, et en fait, il y plusieurs autres cas !

Answer (score 4):

J'ai l'impression que l'on cherche à faire entrer la licence poétique dans une normalisation ISO-ISBN-QQCH.

Bien sûr ***latte*** symbolise une planche (ou une ferraille) longue et étroite

"*à grand coup de* latte *dans l'train* " expression argotique du millénaire passé, pour "botter les fesses" qui vient de (Emile Littré) :  
"*Il se dit quelquefois pour instrument de bastonnade.*
♦ Je fus condamné en plein divan à cent coups de *latte* sur la plante des pieds, rachetables de cinq cents sequins, VOLT., Scarmentado. "

et puis :
♦ Fig. *Grand sabre de cavalerie droit et étroit*. 
Notre hôtel aurait donc subit des assauts "cavaliers" (le comportement cavalier manque de respect, particulièrement pour les dames), son état de dégradation en serait les traces, ce serait donc un bordel, un endroit glauque, canaille?

***latter*** (verbe) toujours selon Émile Littré : 
*Garnir de lattes*, mais surtout : *Terme de marine. Empiler des planches dans un port avec ordre et de manière que l'air puisse circuler entre elles.*
Si notre hôtel n'est plus latté correctement, l'air qu'on y respire ne devrait pas être si bon que cela.

Il commence à me plaire, cet hôtel, histoire d'une vie nocturne, où l'on peut se faire *latter* (et donc en sortir **délatté**), face obscure d'une vie que l'artiste dévoile.